# Disable split.js gutter from dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, split.js

As titled,

Am using Split.js to split 2 blocks contained within a parent block, as shown in the example code below

```
<div id="blocks" class="split-block">
    <div id="blockA" class="split split-horizontal">
        <!-- Block A content in here -->
    </div>
    <div id="blockB" class="split split-horizontal">
        <!-- Block B content in here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And calling Split on blocks

```
// Split js for dividing between blockA and blockB
var split = Split(['#blockA', '#blockB'], {
    sizes: [50, 50],
    gutterSize: 20,
});
```

The way these 2 block works it then, when there is an event in blockA, blockB will start its processes and will be on loading mode, where i put a loading spinner on blockB using [jquery-loading plugin](http://carlosbonetti.github.io/jquery-loading/). The spinner will stay on blockB until processes in blockB is complete.

During the processes time, i want the gutter that splits blockA and blockB to be non draggable, and becomes draggable again after blockB has completed its processes. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Library author here. You can call `split.destroy()` when blockB starts "loading mode" and then create the split again once blockB is complete.

This removes the gutter completely, but you can emulate a gutter with CSS on blockA or blockB border.

Answer (score 0):

A less drastic approach than destroying and recreating the splits every time you want to disable dragging is to set `pointer-events: none;` on the gutter.

```js
const split = new Split( [ '#a', '#b' ], {
   sizes: [ 50, 50 ],
} );

// disable drag
split.pairs.gutter.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

// enable drag
split.pairs.gutter.style.pointerEvents = 'all';

// or just hide the gutter
split.pairs.gutter.style.display= 'none';
```